# Why are Golang type-aliases sometimes compatible and sometimes not?

Tags: go

The following code works just fine:

```golang
type alias []byte

type data struct {
    x alias
}

func main() {
    s2 := []byte("s2")
    s1 := &data{
        x: s2,
    }
    var s4 alias = s2
    fmt.Println(s1,s2, s4)
}
```

but the following doesn't compile

```
type alias string

type data struct {
    x alias
}

func main() {
    s2 := string("s2")
    s1 := &data{
        x: s2, // needs explicit alias(s2)
    }
    var s4 alias = s2 // needs explicit alias(s2)
    fmt.Println(s1,s2, s4)
}
}
```

The only difference is the type alias changes from a slice of bytes to a string.

What's the difference between those types, that the one is auto-converted and the other is not?

Comment: Note that these are not type aliases. See the [Assignability](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability) section in the spec.

Comment: (also, if you do use a type alias, you can assign them directly, because they are the same type:https://play.golang.org/p/bJmbWZt-muE)

Comment: Thanks, yes, they are "type definitions". But the rule with "at least one of V or T is not a defined type" is not quite intuitive...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to the Go langauge spec:

https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability

This specific clause:

> x's type V and T have identical underlying types and at least one of V or T is not a defined type.

And note that, `string` is a defined type and `[]byte` is an undefined type. So:

- You can assign a `[]byte` to `alias` because they have identical underlying types, and `[]byte` is an undefined type
- You cannot assign a `string` to `alias` because they  are both defined types.

Comment: Also `string` isn't just `type string []byte`, they are treated differently by the compiler. Strings are immutable, byte slices are not; and while you can convert freely between `string` and `[]byte`, `range` on a `string` produces `rune` elements, not `byte`s.